# adding menus to black berry application

Tags: blackberry

How can I add menus to my black berry application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your extending the MainScreen it's quite easy! First you'd need to create MenuItem's, this is done like so:

```
private MenuItem _menuItem1 = new MenuItem("Menu Item 1", 10, 10){
    public void run(){
        // insert code thats to be done when menu is selected here here
    }
};  

private MenuItem _menuItem2 = new MenuItem("Menu Item 2", 10, 10){
    public void run(){
        // insert code thats to be done when menu is selected here here
    }
};
```

Then you'd need to add these to your like which is done like so:

```
protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance){
    menu.add(_menuItem1);
    menu.addSeparator();
    menu.add(_menuItem2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry support forums:
[Add a custom menu item to an existing BlackBerry application](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Add-a-custom-menu-item-to-an-existing-BlackBerry-application/ta-p/443026)

Answer (score 0):

```
1.create menu item which you want to add on menu    
MenuItem menuItemBack = new MenuItem(new StringProvider("back"), 110, 10) {
    public void run() {
        Dialog.alert("back");
    }
};
MenuItem menuItemFwd = new MenuItem(new StringProvider("Forword"), 110, 10) {
    public void run() {
        Dialog.alert("forword");
    }
};
2.after that you can add these item on menu by using 
1.add these item in to Mainscreen constructor.
 addMenuItem(menuItemBack);
 addMenuItem(menuItemBack);
    addMenuItem(MenuItem.separator(110));
    addMenuItem(menuItemFwd);
    addMenuItem(MenuItem.separator(110));

 you can create your custom menu by overriding the makeMenu() method
 protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {
 menu.addMenuItem(menuItemBack);
menu.addMenuItem(menuItemFwd);
};
```